# Do database schema changes break linq to entities

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

Do database schema changes break linq to entities?  If so what changes cause it break?

- adding a column to a table
- adding a table
- removing a table
- removing a column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is plenty of changes which breaks EF without updating mapping. For example:

- Adding required column to mapped table - breaks insert and update from EF
- Adding FK constraint to existing column - can break insert or updates
- Removing mapped column - breaks everything working with this entity
- Removing mapped table - breaks everything working with this entity